# I cant solve this problem... Im 17 and I dont know calculus. The topic that this problem was in is Polynomial zeros.

Tags: polynomials

Write the polynomial $p$. $p$ is a 3rd degree polynomial. $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x-0,5)$. $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x+0,5)$. $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x+2)$. When we divide $p$ by $(x-2)$ we get a remainder $-3$.

I know that if polynomial p is divisible polynomial q we can write $p(x) = (x)\cdot q(x) + r(x)$ where $k(x)$ is a quotient and $r(x)$ is the remainder.
I don't know how to solve the problem however.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the polynomial is divisible by $(x-\frac 12)$, $(x+\frac 12)$, $(x-2)$ and has degree 3, you have that
$$
p(x) = c(x-\frac 12)(x+\frac 12)(x+2)
$$

The constant $c$ can be computed from the last condition...

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your information, we know that :
$$P(X)=a(X-0.5)(X+0.5)(X+2) $$

Then you can use your last information to get $a$ :

$$P(X)=Q(X)(X-2)-3 $$

So you know that $P(2)=-3 $

$$a\times 1.5\times 2.5\times 4 =-3$$

So you get :
$$\boxed{a=-0.2} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!